# Synchronize the current app locale with iOS "Preferred language" in App Settings?

Tags: ios, flutter, localization, flutter-getx

In my application on iOS, I have "Suggested languages" in App Settings EN and RU.
I use GetX to change locale as

`Get.updateLocale(Locale('ru'))`

The app is localized immediately on RU, but in iOS Settings, the "Preferred language" is not updated it's still EN.

How to synchronize the current app locale with iOS "Preferred language" in App Settings?

[image]

Comment: I want accomplish this feature too. Do you have any implementation?

Answer (score -2):

Add this code in MaterialApp() in main.dart

```
localeListResolutionCallback:(locales, supportedLocales){
  if(locales != null && locales.isNotEmpty){
    if(locales.first.languageCode == 'de'){
      UserPreferences().saveData(UserPreferences.SHARED_USER_LANGUAGE, 'de');
     return const Locale('de','');
    }else{
      UserPreferences().saveData(UserPreferences.SHARED_USER_LANGUAGE, 'en');
      return const Locale('en','');
    }
  }
},
```